# Connection refused from filebeat to logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack, filebeat

I have an issue when I try to connect to my `logstash` from `Filebeat`

```
Logstash version 2.0.0
Filebeat 1.0.1
```

Here the error

> INFO Connecting error publishing events (retrying): dial tcp 192.168.50.5:14560: getsockopt: connection refused

This is my logstash configuration

```
input {
    beats {
        codec => json
        port => 14560
    }
}
output {
    elasticsearch { hosts=> localhost}
    stdout {codec = > rubydebug}
}
```

Here my filebeat configuration

```
   logstash:
   # The Logstash hosts
   hosts: ["192.168.50.5:14560","192.168.50.15:14560"]
```

I install the filebeat logstash plugin as I have read it

```
 ./plugin install logstash-input-beats
```

I have completely run out of ideas, and I would love to use this framework, but it seems not to be responding at all. 
Any ideas would be great.

Comment: Why do you have curly braces around the hosts in the filebeat configuration?

Comment: Ups wrong copy/paste. I change it as I have

Answer (score 2):

This happens when your logstash is not up or the logstash host is not getting connected (due to firewall maybe) from the host running filebeat . Try doing a telnet to 192.168.50.5 14560 from the host you are running filebeat.

Comment: Ugh, I can't believe I didn't think about this. I had that same problem and it turned out the Logstash service was not started on our server. Thank you!